# Should questions about algorithms be tagged a language?

Tags: support, tags

[What algorithm maps each element from set A to it best match in set B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073658/what-algorithm-maps-each-element-from-set-a-to-it-best-match-in-set-b) caught my eye, and I'm sure there will be or are other questions like this one. The question asks about an algorithm to find strings that are more similar than other strings and the question is tagged C#. The question and any suitable answers (with the exception of libraries I suppose) will most likely be language independent. I understand asking for it an answer most suited to be implemented in a particular language, but should the question be tagged with a language?

Comment: Related: [Why do people specify language when asking language-agnostic algorithm questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41305)

Answer (score 2):

I think the poster should feel free to tag it in whatever language they need it in — it's not a hindrance to anything to include a language, even in a language-agnostic question, as it gives a hint as to which language example code (if any) might be provided in.